# Git Bash upgraded to v2.41, but now the very basic command `git fetch` is not working

Tags: filesystems, git-bash, windows-11, git-fetch, git-for-windows

After GitBash has been upgraded to [v2.41.x](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.41.0.windows.3) in Windows 11 64bit, some basic commands like `git fetch` have apparently stopped working.

Now, if I run any of `fetch` command derivatives like `git fetch`/`git fetch origin`/`git fetch --all -p` etc., it non-sensically throws this error:

```
usage: git rev-list [<options>] <commit-id>... [-- <path>...]
  limiting output:
    --max-count=<n>
    --max-age=<epoch>
    --min-age=<epoch>
    --sparse
    --no-merges
    --min-parents=<n>
    --no-min-parents
    --max-parents=<n>
    --no-max-parents
    --remove-empty
    --all
    --branches
    --tags
    --remotes
    --stdin
    --quiet
  ordering output:
    --topo-order
    --date-order
    --reverse
  formatting output:
    --parents
    --children
    --objects | --objects-edge
    --unpacked
    --header | --pretty
    --[no-]object-names
    --abbrev=<n> | --no-abbrev
    --abbrev-commit
    --left-right
    --count
  special purpose:
    --bisect
    --bisect-vars
    --bisect-all
error: bitbucket.org:<company-name>/<repository-name>.git did not send all necessary objects
```

And I am 100% sure, these commands were working without any of above errors when the GitBash's version v2.37 was installed just a while ago.

Can anyone assist in understanding what's wrong with Gitbash here and how to fix it ??